# Azure web app Connect to SQL Database random error

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-managed-identity, azure-sql-server

I have an azure web application running that need to connect to an Azure SQL Database.
My testing approach is to authenticate the web app by using Managed identity.

So in my web app I activated the managed identity, after that I logged into my database and run the following script:

```
CREATE USER [<identity-name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
```

Saved and updated the connection string of my database into my web app and restarted.
Everything worked perfectly for a couple of hours, after that I start getting this error:

```
Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'.
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CheckPoolBlockingPeriod(Exception e)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
```

This is kind f confusing me because after the restart of the wb app, I can see that the web app is able to connect to the database and retrieve data..but suddenly after a couple of hours it starts throwing that error.

Did this occurred to anybody before and can direct me on the right path to solve this issue?

Goes without saying that I updated my Entityframework and Data.SqlClient to the correct version to facilitate this approach as documented.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide

Comment: Could you share the code that get the access_token to connect to the db ? Looks like you re only getting it once but the token expires after X minutes.

Comment: Also is it .net framework or net core ?